# <h:commandButton> doesn't call method

Tags: jsf, action, managed-bean, commandbutton

I have a `<h:commandButton>`

```
   <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="uri" value="#{pesquisaBean.selectedUri}" />
        <f:event listener="#{pesquisaBean.searchElement()}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:head>
        <title>Detalhes do Documento</title>
    </h:head>

       <h:body>
       <br />
       Detalhes do Documento

       <br />
       <br />
       <rich:dataTable value="#{pesquisaBean.documentDetailsByTitle}" var="result">

                <c:forEach items="#{pesquisaBean.variableNamesDetails}" var="vname">
                     <rich:column>
                         <f:facet name="header">#{vname}</f:facet>
                          #{result[vname]}
                     </rich:column> 

                </c:forEach> 
       </rich:dataTable>
       <br />
       <h:commandButton value="Excluir" action="#{pesquisaBean.delete()}" />
       <br />
       <br />
```

and this action method

```
  public void delete() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    this.removeDocument(databaseModel, this.selectedDocument);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("After deleting!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    StmtIterator result = databaseModel.listStatements();
    while( result.hasNext() ) {
        Statement stmt = result.next();
        System.out.println(stmt);
    }
```

However, the command button doesn't call the action method.
I'm trying to print `Hello` in the first line of the method, but it isn't printed.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please show xhtml code.

Comment: Please show the rest of your pesquisaBean

Comment: possible duplicate of [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess, you didn't enclose `<h:commandButton/>` with `<h:form/>`. Try to call like:

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandButton value="Excluir" action="#{pesquisaBean.delete()}" />
</h:form>
```

Whenever, you will working with JSF, always open development environment by writing following `context-param` in `web.xml`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It will show warning, what is missing in xhtml.